# Unable to remove the software raid-1 array when it is in degraded state

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm, raid1

I want to remove the software raid-1 array [ when it is degraded state] configured on LVM in linux system and unable to remove the same. I have even tried using Knoppix Live CD to remove the RAID-1 associated to LVM, but this attempt also failed. When i analyzed the issue, there is a LVM configured along with RAID and the logical volume (vg0-root) is mounted on "/" filesystem. Could you please suggest any way to delete this Raid-1 array with out loss of data.

Please find out the configuration of system:

```
root@:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000bb738

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    34613373    17305663   da  Non-FS data
/dev/sdb4   *    34613374   156248189    60817408   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000bb738

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    34613373    17305663   da  Non-FS data
/dev/sda4   *    34613374   156248189    60817408   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.


root@:~# lsblk
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1                    8:1    0  16.5G  0 part
└─sda4                    8:4    0    58G  0 part
  └─md0                   9:0    0    58G  0 raid1
    ├─vg0-swap (dm-0)   252:0    0   1.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─vg0-root (dm-1)   252:1    0  19.6G  0 lvm   /
    └─vg0-backup (dm-2) 252:2    0  19.6G  0 lvm
sdb                       8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sdb1                    8:17   0  16.5G  0 part
└─sdb4                    8:20   0    58G  0 part

root@S761012:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sda4[0]
      60801024 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>


root@:~# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed Sep 23 02:59:04 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 60801024 (57.98 GiB 62.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 60801024 (57.98 GiB 62.26 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Mar  7 23:38:20 2017
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : Raja:0
           UUID : 8b007464:369201ca:13634910:1d1d4bbf
         Events : 823063

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        4        0      active sync   /dev/sda4
       1       0        0        1      removed


root@:~# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda4
mdadm: set device faulty failed for /dev/sda4:  Device or resource busy

root@:~# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sda4
mdadm: hot remove failed for /dev/sda4: Device or resource busy

root@:~# mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md0:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?


    root@:~# pvdisplay
      --- Physical volume ---
      PV Name               /dev/md0
      VG Name               vg0
      PV Size               57.98 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
      Allocatable           yes
      PE Size               4.00 MiB
      Total PE              14843
      Free PE               4361
      Allocated PE          10482
      PV UUID               uxH3FS-sUOF-LsIP-kAjq-7Bwq-suhK-CLJXI1

    root@:~#:~# lvdisplay
      --- Logical volume ---
      LV Path                /dev/vg0/swap
      LV Name                swap
      VG Name                vg0
      LV UUID                BIwp5H-NYlf-drQJ-12Vf-5qYM-7NUj-ty9GhE
      LV Write Access        read/write
      LV Creation host, time S000001, 2015-09-23 03:00:58 +0000
      LV Status              available
      # open                 2
      LV Size                1.86 GiB
      Current LE             476
      Segments               1
      Allocation             inherit
      Read ahead sectors     auto
      - currently set to     256
      Block device           252:0

      --- Logical volume ---
      LV Path                /dev/vg0/root
      LV Name                root
      VG Name                vg0
      LV UUID                SBf1mc-iqaB-noBx-1neo-IEPi-HhsH-SM14er
      LV Write Access        read/write
      LV Creation host, time S000001, 2015-09-23 03:01:19 +0000
      LV Status              available
      # open                 1
      LV Size                19.54 GiB
      Current LE             5003
      Segments               1
      Allocation             inherit
      Read ahead sectors     auto
      - currently set to     256
      Block device           252:1

      --- Logical volume ---
      LV Path                /dev/vg0/backup
      LV Name                backup
      VG Name                vg0
      LV UUID                w1jGGy-KkfJ-0lDp-MFDl-8BJU-uJWU-24XKSL
      LV Write Access        read/write
      LV Creation host, time SRAJA, 2016-10-22 05:30:03 +0000
      LV Status              available
      # open                 0
      LV Size                19.54 GiB
      Current LE             5003
      Segments               1
      Allocation             inherit
      Read ahead sectors     auto
      - currently set to     256
      Block device           252:2

    root@:~# vgdisplay
      --- Volume group ---
      VG Name               vg0
      System ID
      Format                lvm2
      Metadata Areas        1
      Metadata Sequence No  674
      VG Access             read/write
      VG Status             resizable
      MAX LV                0
      Cur LV                3
      Open LV               2
      Max PV                0
      Cur PV                1
      Act PV                1
      VG Size               57.98 GiB
      PE Size               4.00 MiB
      Total PE              14843
      Alloc PE / Size       10482 / 40.95 GiB
      Free  PE / Size       4361 / 17.04 GiB
      VG UUID               LjCUyX-25MQ-WCFT-j2eF-2UWX-LYCp-TtLVJ5
```

Lastly i tried to do:

```
 root@S761012:~# mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/md0
 mdadm: Couldn't open /dev/md0 for write - not zeroing
```

root@:~# umount /dev/md0
    umount: /dev/md0: not mounted
    root@:~#
    root@:~# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sda4
    mdadm: hot remove failed for /dev/sda4: Device or resource busy
    root@:~# mdadm --stop /dev/md0
    mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md0:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?
    root@:~# mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda4
    mdadm: Couldn't open /dev/sda4 for write - not zeroing

Since sda4 is the active disk, it is not allowing me to do any operations. 
Could you please suggest any other ways to achieve the same.

- Tried with the knoppix live and Gparted live CD, result is same.

I tried to use as mentioned steps:

```
create new log file
select /dev/sda and press Proceed
select Intel/PC partition type
select Analyse
select Backup (at first starting `testdisk`) or select Quick Search and Press Enter
select Deeper Search   -> After deep search is not showing any thing.
```

->  **No partition  found or selected for recovery.** It is empty. Due to which Boot repair also not working as expected. Always it is going to grub rescue mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before all you must understand how it works. Partitions work over whole disk sda, software RAID works over partitions and next as in diagram:

Disk sda -> partition sda4 -> software RAID md0 -> LVM physical volume -> LVM volume group vg0 -> LVM logical volume -> filesystem -> system mount point.

You can't unmount root filesystem from command line interface which is running from it. That's why you need run same Linux system from CD/DVD. You can use same Linux install CD or last version [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage). You need check after starting from CD:

- Is software RAID starting and his state by command `cat /proc/mdstat`? RAID device `md` may have another number.
- Is LVM volume group active by command `vgdisplay`?
- Are filesystems (on LVM volumes) mounted by command `mount`?

Then unmount all filesystems which are placed on LVM volumes by command `umount`, deactivate LVM volume group vg0 by command `vgchange -a n vg0`, shut down the RAID array by command `mdadm --stop /dev/md0`,  remove the RAID device by command `mdadm --remove /dev/md0` and only then zero the superblock on sda4 by command `mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda4`.

Before all you need to backup all files on all LVM volumes filesystems.

May be you will restore grub boot loader.

Updates:

Before restoring boot you need to restore LVM! Boot your system again from SystemResqueCD. Run `fdisk /dev/sda` and press:

```
t (type)
4
8e (Linux LVM)
w
```

Then run `testdisk`:

```
create new log file
select /dev/sda and press Proceed
select Intel/PC partition type
select Analyse
select Backup (at first starting `testdisk`) or select Quick Search and Press Enter
select Deeper Search
select Linux LVM with heights start CHS values and press space key to change this found structure as Primary partition and press enter
select Write
```

Then store testdisk's backup somewhere by `scp backup.log user@somehost:~`
and reboot again from SystemResqueCD. 
after reboot you can see your volumegroup `vg0` by command vgdisplay. If it isn't then run `testdisk` again, load testdisk's backup and start again with another founded Linux LVM partition.

After succesfully restoring LVM you can restore boot as described at [Ubuntu Boot repair](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/boot_repair).

Comment: mdadm --stop /dev/md0 command worked using SystemRescueCD. Are they any tools in SystemRescueCD to take backup of LVM filesystems, if so could you please let me know.

Comment: You can use tar gzip scp rsync ftp dd FSArchiver

PartImage Gparted.

Comment: After i did, mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda4, the Linux machine is going to grub resuce mode>  and machine boot loader got corrupted. I tried with boot repair disk, still no sucess. Do you have any inputs or suggestions to recover for this issue.

Comment: What Linux version was on your HDD?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 LTS Kernel 3.13-0-85

Comment: Can you help me, how to do reload the grub after mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda4 command.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late answer. I was very busy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will try and let us know the result soon,

Comment: I followed the steps as mentioned, in the testdisk after Quick search  and deeper search , I am seeing the message as "No partition is found". But after Analyse , i could see p sys=DA and   "No lvm or Lvm2 structure message followed by * Linux LVM data repeated two times.

Comment: Then you need to  recovery from backup.

Comment: It's a pity. I tested this on fresh Ubuntu 14.04 installation.

Comment: Came from web search hoping to find information about how to remove failed MD raid, found none in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to revert to 'single user' mode using the shutdown command, and then unmount the volume whilst in single-user mode.  At that point, the RAID-1 volume won't be in use, and you should be able to delete the RAID array.

*shutdown now* should bring you to single-user.

*shutdown -h now* will halt the system

*shutdown -r now* will restart it

*shutdown --help* gives you all the options of the command, including sending messages to logged-in users that you're taking the system to single-user mode.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late response. I have tried by above suggestion, but still i am facing the same errors.                                             root@:~# umount /dev/md0
umount: /dev/md0: not mounted
root@:~#
root@:~# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sda4
mdadm: hot remove failed for /dev/sda4: Device or resource busy
root@:~# mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md0:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?
root@:~# mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda4
mdadm: Couldn't open /dev/sda4 for write - not zeroing

Comment: Looks like the reason is what Mikhail pointed out - even in single-user mode, your kernel is still using the drive (because that's where it was booted from.)  So you'll need to bring the system up using a USB or CD Live Boot, and then work with the array.